# How to plot periodic data with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

My data recording system has center values [0,10,20,...350], and the data is assumed to collected evenly from the center points. Therefore, I want to plot histogram binned in this way: [-5,5],[5,15],[15,25] ... [345, 355].

The problem is that, the data are stored in [0, 360], which would make the inital and end sector just half of the data.

Simply put, when I want to plot the data for [-5,5], the actual data ploted would just have **half the size**, since [-5,5] is split into [0,5] and [355,360]. You can look at the `0`,`355` bin at the pic below.

```
bins=np.arange(-5, 360 + 10, 10)
df['dir'].hist(bins=bins, alpha=0.5, figsize=(15, 3))
```

[image]

My questions are:

1. What would be a good way to plot circular data, so I can solve the `half size` problem?
2. The plot has an emply sector start at `-50`, is there way to get rid of it?

Comment: 2nd question: If you want to have more control over the looks `hist` plot, make your own by reading the histogram values out and passing them into a bar plot.  `numpy.histogram` returns an array of the bincounts and the edges.   1st question: What about a polar bar plot like http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/pylab_examples/polar_bar.html ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1:
if you don't want the beautiful polar plot suggested by roadrunner, and instead want to keep your linear bar chart, you should assign any values > 355 to the 0 bin, eg,

```
wrapped = np.array(df['dir'])
wrapped[wrapped > 355] = 0
plt.hist(wrapped, bins=np.arange(0,370,10), align='left')
```

(align='left' plots your bins from, eg, -5..5, 5..15, etc given data values ranging from 0..355)

2: 
now get rid of that unwanted space on the left with:

```
plt.axis('tight')
```

Comment: Never know there is a `tight` option. I was trying set `align: right`

Comment: Hi, can you tell me where is the documentation for it? I want to only set `tight` for x axis. y is not necessery.